# Javascript Object Not Empty (But it should be)

Tags: javascript

I am encountering very strange behavior in Javascript, which I have never seen before. Below is a general example of the problem I am seeing:

```
var myObject = {};
$.each(myDict,function(k,v){
    myObject[k]={nodes:[],links:[]};
    console.log(myObject[v]);
    //then perform some calculations to create a var link and a var node
    myObject[k].links.push(link);
    myObject[k].nodes.push(node); 
})
```

When I do the console.log(myObject[v]), it will show "Object {nodes: Array[0], links: Array[0]}", which is what is expected. However, when I expand that (in the console), it shows "links: Array[35]" and "nodes: Array[40]". I have also checked to make sure the links and nodes I am pushing have the correct values, and they do, however *they do not even appear in myObject[k].link even immediately after they were pushed*. Instead, the links and nodes mysteriously already in myObject[v] have random null fields all over the place, which is impossible, given that none of the links and nodes I generate have such field values.

I can't figure out why in the world myObject isn't empty. I have also tried deleting the object using "delete", but to no avail--I suspected this could be some memory management issue. This behavior is extremely odd. It is also worth nothing that if I change the dictionary field names, it works fine a single time, and then after that I encounter the same problem.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Are you only confused about the console display or is the actually affecting your working code. Consoles often give a "live" view of an object, so you get the state it's in when you expand it, not when you logged it,.

Answer (score -1):

Push without mentioning [k] index.

```
 myObject.links.push(link);
```